# How, in wordpress, define whether custom checkbox of a post is checked and based on that display predefined word (for instance: video)?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

To note, the label video means the post has a video inside.
My code which is below is not successful.

````
<?php 

 $new_query = array(
'posts_per_page' => 100,
'orderby' => 'publish_date',
'order' => 'DESC',
 );

 if ( $new_query->have_posts() ) {
 while ( $new_query->have_posts() ) {
    $new_query->the_post();

 <div id="news">
    <a id="s1ustlink" href="<?php the_permalink();?>" target="_blank">
    
    <div id="up">

    <div id="left">     
        <img src="<?php the_field('image'); ?>"/>
    </div>
   
    <div id="right">
        <p id="article"><?php the_title();?></p>
        <p id="media1" <?php          $adcat = get_field('additional_category');
                                      $adcatimploded = implode(',', $adcat);
                                      if (in_array($adcatimploded, 'video')) {
   echo {'style="display:block"';}   

   ?> >Video</p>
        <p id="media2">Photo</p>
        <p id="media3">Updated</p>
    </div>
    </div></a>
    <div id="down">
   <div id="time"><i class='fa fa-clock-o' style='font-size:90%'></i>
   <p><?php the_time();?> | <?php echo get_the_date('d.m.Y', get_the_ID()) ?></p>
   </div>
   <div id="post-view"><?php pvc_post_views(); ?></div>
   </div>
   </div>

   <?php
    endwhile;
      endif;
   ?>```
````

by default, in css, display value of media1 is none;

```
    #media1 {
      float: left;
      padding: 2px;
      border: 2px solid red;
      border-radius: 10px;
      display: none;
      background-color: gold
     }
```

Comment: `if (in_array($adcatimploded, 'video'))` – `in_array` works the other way around - the first parameter is the _needle_, the second one the _haystack_. But after `$adcatimploded = implode(',', $adcat);`, that variable won’t even contain an _array_ to begin with.

Comment: let me correct and see

Comment: @cbroe not successfull anyhow. it doesn't show up anything.

Comment: First of all, _show us_ what you actually changed. Otherwise, how could we possibly tell, whether you still did something wrong.

Comment: @Cbroe I edited (in_array($adcatimploded, 'video')) as (in_array('video', $adcatimploded)) and removed imploded section

Comment: no, I meant as (in_array('video', $adcat))

Comment: And “it doesn't show up anything” means what exactly now - that the whole page stopped working? Then you likely introduced a syntax error somewhere, go check the error log then. Or something else?

Comment: @Cbroe the code is smooth loop shows all the post but there should be video labels on the ones where video chechbox is checked. It's not displaying

Comment: Well then do a bit of debugging … Start by making a debug output of what `$adcat` actually contains. (Don’t make it “inside” the `<p …>` tag, otherwise you likely won’t be able to see it in the frontend.)

Comment: $Cbroe )) I think I'm ruining your time, thanks for responding but it's nothing to do with the tags. Whatever wrong is related to the php functions.

Comment: _“but it's nothing to do with the tags”_ - how would you know, if you did not actually debug this, right there in that specific place? Do not naively _assume_ that you variables must have specific values, always _verify_ that!